# Travis add pull_request_branch into slack template on pull requests

Tags: integration, travis-ci, slack

i've seen on the variables page(https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) that you're able to get 'pul_request_branch' which is the original branch you're pulling from. I want to use this in a template like so:

```
- "Build <%{build_url}|#%{build_number}> (<%{compare_url}|%{commit}>) of %{repository_slug}@%{pull_request_branch} in PR <%{pull_request_url}|#%{pull_request_number}> by %{author} %{result} in %{duration}"
```

But i get the following message in slack:

```
Build #1234 (abcdef12) of repo-slug@
```

If i just use branch then i get repo-slug@master where i'm expecting something more like repo-slug@working-branch

Can someone help please

Comment: found this: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/travis-ci/travis-yaml/Travis/Yaml/Nodes/Notifications/Template looks like it might not actually be possible. damnit